# Artifactory host name resolution to docker registry

Tags: url, nginx, artifactory, docker-registry

I am trying to push a docker image into a newly created docker repo in Artifactory. For this I tag the image as follows,

```
docker tag ubuntu mNginxLb.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/docker/<repo_key>
```

and then push the image but get the following error

```
docker push  mNginxLb.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/docker/<repo_key>/ubuntu

The push refers to a repository [mNginxLb.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/docker/<repo_key>/ubuntu] (len: 1)
unable to ping registry endpoint https://mNginxLb.mycompany.com/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://mNginxLb.mycompany.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://mNginxLb.mycompany.com/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Is this a problem with the certificate signing authority or with the hostname resolution? I checked to see if other repositories work well with the SSL certificate so I am not sure if the problem is of the certificates. 
Here is my nginx conf:

```
upstream artifactory_lb {
            server mNginxLb.mycompany.com:8081;
            server mNginxLb.mycompany.com backup;
    }

    log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';

    server {
            listen 80;
            listen 443 ssl;

            ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/my-certs/myCert.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my-certs/myserver.key;
            client_max_body_size 2048M;
            location / {
                    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                    proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
                    proxy_read_timeout 90;
            }
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
            location /basic_status {
                    stub_status on;
                    allow all;
                    }
    }

    # Server configuration

    server {
        listen 2222 ssl;

        server_name mNginxLb.mycompany.com;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
            set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
        }

        rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/my_local_repo_key/$1/$2;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        location / {
        proxy_read_timeout  900;
        proxy_pass_header   Server;
        proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass         http://artifactory_lb;
        proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

After updating the certificate to one by CA, this error goes away , although I still cant push images and get a 403 forbidden error. The command I use is

```
 docker push host:port/The push refers to a repository [host:port/image_name] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Error: Status 403 trying to push repository ubuntu: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.22 - Error report</title><style type=\"text/css\">H1 {f
ont-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#5
25D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;c
olor:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;backgro
und:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><bod
y><h1>HTTP Status 403 - </h1><div class=\"line\"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Access to the speci
fied resource has been forbidden.</u></p><hr class=\"line\"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.22</h3></body></html>"image_name
```

The docker client gives the following error 
 While the artifactory logs show the following

```
"GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 466 "-" "docker/1.9.1 go/go1.4.2 git-commit/a34a1d5 kernel/3.13.0-24-generic os/linux arch/amd64"
172.28.144.202 - - [22/Dec/2015:11:06:00 -0500] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 466 "-" "docker/1.9.1 go/go1.4.2 git-commit/a34a1d5 kernel/3.13.0-24-generic os/linux arch/amd64"
 "GET /v1/_ping HTTP/1.1" 404 470 "-" "docker/1.9.1 go/go1.4.2 git-commit/a34a1d5 kernel/3.13.0-24-generic ] "PUT /v1/repositories/ubuntu/ HTTP/1.1" 403 449 "-" "docker/1.9.1 go/go1.4.2 git-commit/a34a1d5 kernel/3.13.0-24-generic os/linux arch/amd64"
```

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate or one from a CA?

Comment: I am using one from CA

Comment: Do you think the forbidden error is for certificate authentication?

Comment: The "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" error indicates that this might be the problem

Comment: I am sorry I updated the question

Comment: I suggest also updating the question with the current docker client output and relevant Artifactory log entries, such as the ones mentioned in your comment to shayy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had configured artifactory with the V1 docker API but was trying to push an image that supported the v2 API

Answer (score 2):

Docker treats everything after the hostname as the repository name (with optionally a namespace) and the tag.
This means you need to use the port you have assigned (2222) with the hostname only.
The context path is going to be the repository name.

In your case it should be:

`docker tag ubuntu mNginxLb.mycompany.com:2222/ubuntu`

`docker push mNginxLb.mycompany.com:2222/ubuntu`

Notice that the `latest` tag is implicit. Another example could be:

`docker tag ubuntu:15.10 mNginxLb.mycompany.com:2222/ubuntu:15.10`

Comment: Should it also have the <repo-key> from teh artifactory? mNginxLb.mycompany.com:2222/my_local_repo_key/ubuntu

Comment: I tried the above with the local repo but its gets a bad request, there are no error in the nginx logs

Comment: You don't need the repo-key since you already use that in the reverse proxy config. As I've mentioned, Docker takes everything in the path and use that as your image name so you can't have anything there except the host and port.

Comment: Bad request (400) could mean you try pushing V1 to V2 or vice-versa. If you are using docker >= 1.6 make sure your repo is configured to V2.

Comment: Thanks shayy, I tried pushing the image by tagging it host:port/image_name. Now I am running into a 403 -forbidden error. I have set the repo to allow anonymous access. Should  thisbe set to authentication first before pushing any images"? What is the command to push with credentials?

Comment: My repo is configured to v2, how do I make sure I am trying to access v2 in the docker push command? The nginx access logs show PUT /v1/repositories/ubuntu/ HTTP/1.1" 403 449 "-" "docker/1.9.1 go/go1.4.2 git-commit/a34a1d5 kernel/3.13.0-24-generic os/linux arch/amd64